# What does zerocenter normalization mean? How could I do this with keras?

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I was checking the design of [AlexNet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlexNet) in MATLAB which is summarized as follows:
[image]

The input layer says `227x227x3` with `zerocenter` normalization. What does `zerocenter` normalization mean? How could I do this keras?

I was going through the [preprocessing documentation at keras](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) and was not sure if any of the following attributes satisfy `zerocenter` normalization? The attributes as also given in the documentation are:

```
 - featurewise_center
 - samplewise_center
 - featurewise_std_normalization
 - samplewise_std_normalization
```

Answer (score 4):

Zero center normalization typically means that images are normalized to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. If your images are NumPy arrays, you can easily achieve this:

```py
img = (img - img.mean()) / img.std()
```

`samplewise_center` and `samplewise_std_normalization` do the same thing, making sure that each image has a mean of 0 and standard deviation 1. If you want to use the mean/std of the dataset, instead of samplewise mean/std, I guess you should do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `zerocenter` normalization in MATLAB has been specified in `imageInputLayer` [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/nnet.cnn.layer.imageinputlayer.html):

> - `'zerocenter'` — Subtract the average image specified by the `AverageImage` property. The `trainNetwork` function automatically computes the average image at training time.

Therefore, the mean image is subtracted from input images to make them have a mean of zero (this helps with a smooth and faster optimization process during training of the model). So, the equivalent option in Keras would be `featurewise_center`:

> - `featurewise_center`: Boolean. Set input mean to 0 over the dataset, feature-wise.

Note that you need to call the `fit()` method of `ImageDataGenerator` to compute the mean image:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, ...)

datagen.fit(train_data) 

# now you can call `flow`
```

Comment: Can't I just use `fit_generator` function on `model`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta The mean image first needs to be computed, in order to subtract it from input images when the generator is passed to the `fit_generator`. So you first need to call the `fit` method of the **generator** and then after that you can start training by calling the `fit_generator` method of **model** which takes the generator as input.

Comment: Okay. Could you explain the difference between `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization`? Also, how is it different from `samplewise_center`?

Comment: @SuhailGupta `featurewise_std_normalization`: this would divide the input images by the standard deviation (i.e. std) of all the images in the dataset; therefore they would all have an std of 1 (featurewise). `samplewise_center`: this would subtract the mean of each input image **from itself**; therefore, the average of pixel values in **each individual** image is zero. All of these are various ways of normalization which are sometimes combined with each other (e.g. featurewise center + std).

Comment: Are there other benefits of zercenter normalization other than faster convergence?

Comment: @SuhailGupta As far as I know, it would mostly help with the optimization process. However, there might be other small benefits by making the model more robust to some image distortions. As an example, consider two images taken from the same scene, but one with less light and another with more light. So in an ideal case, if all the pixels in the darker image be shifted by the same amount we would reach the brighter image. Applying zerocenter would make these two images more or less equal and therefore the model would have an easier learning path. Though, this is an ideal case.